# Non-existant URL redirects to existant one

Tags: posts

I have the **pet-insurance-reviews** URI under my website, which redirects to **review-for-pet-insurance** after update of the permalinks.

The WordPress Object cache was flushed using WP CLI.
There is no **post_name** record in the MySQL **wp_post** table with **pet-insurance-reviews**

The .htaccess file is default WordPress .htaccess

Comment: This can very easily be that your browser has cached the redirect if it was (301) as it normally does. Try to open up a private windows or incognito mode. Try to navigate to the permalinks page to be sure you have flushed the redirect cache.

Answer (score 0):

If with "update of the permalinks" you mean updating the post's slug:

WordPress uses a function called `wp_old_slug_redirect()` to find out if you're looking for a post whose slug was recently changed and redirect you to its new home.